Parallel decorator on Numba routine featuring race condition
I have the following routine aiming to calculate in parallel different SVD of random matrices:
import numpy as np 
from numba import jit,prange 

@jit(nopython=True,parallel=True)
def svd_bn(aa,n):
    
    res=[]
    for k in prange(n):
        u,s,v=np.linalg.svd(aa[k],0)
        res.append( s ) 
        
        
    return res
aa=[np.random.rand(2*k,2*(k+1)) for k in range(1,10)]

res=svd_bn(aa,len(aa))

On a Windows OS, this works fine and returns the sorted elements in the list. On a Linux OS, this leads to a "double free or corruption (!prev)" error. My suspicion is that the parallelization on Linux leads to a race condition that is avoided on Windows, plus the "res" list is changing its entries dynamically.
Is there a way to overcome this problem using Numba? Note that in principle we don't know the shape of the u,s,v arrays returned from the routine.

You cannot use res.append( s ) in a parallel loop because this operation is inherently sequential. This cause the race condition. Numba do not check if a code is correct, it is your job. You need to preallocate the output to the right size and set the item.

About the preallocation, if we don't know beforehand what the dimensions from the SVD will be, I only see as a solution to preallocate "larger" arrays, and just put the solution on top of those and later reduce the elements... or is there another way to preallocate this without knowing the output dimensions?

You know the size of the list is n so you can preallocate the list with N items and then set the Numpy arrays. They just need to be of the good type. That being said, AFAIK there is a Numba bug in cases like this and Numpy array are sometimes not set correctly... IDK if it has been fixed or if it will happen in your case. Note the Numba list will be converted to a reflected list and this might be expensive too (the same thing is true for the input) though the SVD should be more expensive.

We need to clarify the question. "ndim" and "shape" are different things in this context. If the ndim of s is constant, as in the example you provided, then you can pre-allocate res even if the shape is different. However, if the ndim is different, then it gets a little more complicated.

@ken If the number of dimension would be different, then the Numba code would not even compile since the number of dimension if part of the type in Numba and Numba lists should be typed list nowadays and so they must have a type which mean that the dimension of all the item of a list must be the same. It may changes from one run to another though which is yet another thing (and not the case in the example). Since the shape of the input changes between items in the example, then I guess it meant "shape" and not "ndim". Still, yes, clarifications are always a good thing.
